# Laravel show validation errors with SweetAlert

Tags: laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am want to use SweetAlert to show the validation errors

In success case I am returning the success message successfully

Controller

```
return redirect(route('home'))->withSuccessMessage('Your Message Sent Successfully');
```

Home route

```
if (session('success_message')) {
    Alert::success('Success!', session('success_message'));
}
```

This worked as expected but I don not know how to show the errors in the pop up

I made this but it's not working

Controller

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $errors = $validator->errors();
    return redirect(route('home'))->withErrorMessage($errors);
}
```

Home route

```
if (session('error_message')) {
    Alert::html('Error', $errors, 'error');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
Alert::error('Error Title', 'Error Message');
```

Comment: I need to display the errors from the validator not simple text